# UITableView's tableFooterView being displayed in very strange ways

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController configured in interface builder. It contains a UITableView, and a UIView as a header and another UIView as a footer.

(Please note, these two UIViews that are acting as headers and footers are NOT section header and footer.)

The header is working just great. In interface builder, the UITableView is aligned to the superview (top: 0, bottom: 0, leading: 0, trailing: 0). Then I aligned the headerView (UIView) to the top of the UITableView, giving it equal width and horizontal centering to the UITableView as well. The height of the headerView is configured according to its subview.

In the .m file, I set

```
    self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
```

Everything works perfectly. Sure enough, the headerView is fixed to the top of the UITableView, and when you scroll down the headerView scrolls with it, disappearing from the screen. Excellent.

I thought I would do the same thing with the footer. Indeed, I did the exact same thing, except I aligned the bottom of the footerView to the UITableView (yes, the two share equal widths and horizontal centering as well). I set the footerView height to be some fixed value.

In the .m file, I add this line of code:

```
   self.myTableView.tableFooterView = self.footerView;
```

And this is where it gets weird... When I scroll to the bottom, there is space for the UIView footerView, exactly according to the height of the footerView that I specified in interface builder.

And when I scroll back up, holding my finger on the scroll to go PAST the top of the UITableView, the subviews of the footerView are UP THERE! WTF!

Does anyone understand this?

Everything is configured in Interface Builder, and the tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties are assigned in the viewDidLoad: method.

Comment: Have you tried to assign the properties of the header and footer in viewDidLayoutSubviews: instead of viewDidLoad:?

Comment: When setting the footer and header properties in viewDidLayoutSubviews, the footerView is visible in the bottom portion of the screen, without scrolling down (kind of in the middle of the UITableView). When I scroll down, it moves up with the table view cells... not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ugly, hacky solution, so far.

The footerView and the UITableView have their bottoms aligned, and I connect that constraint to the .m file as a property (bottomToBottomConstraint). I then set myTableView.contentSize.height to be the bottomToBottomConstraint.constant, and the view appears where I want it to be.

```
    self.bottomToBottomConstraint.constant = self.myTableView.contentSize.height;
```

While it is just one line of code, I would prefer understanding the problem and implementing a true solution... awaiting your knowledge!